# Stripe not allowing updating of connected account due to permissions?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm attempting to create a new external bank account on a stripe connected account like so:

```
      await stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(existingAccount.id, {
                default_for_currency: true,
                external_account: {
                    routing_number: bsb,
                    account_number: accountNumber,
                    account_holder_name: accountName,
                    country: 'AU',
                    currency: 'AUD',
                    object: 'bank_account',
                    account_holder_type: 'individual'
                }
            })
```

Where existingAccount.id is the id of the connected account.

This creates the error:

`This application does not have the required permissions for this endpoint on account 'acct_[Account ID]`.

The connected account is an express account, when first created I give it a bank account and want the connected account user to be able to change/update it from within the app.

I'm not sure why this is creating permission issues and can't find any setings around permissions, the key I used to create the account is the same one I'm using to add a new external account to the created account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving that error because you cannot create an external account for Express accounts. For context, Express accounts are expected to manage their own bank accounts from their Stripe Express Dashboard.

Comment: ah ok thank you, weird I thought it was working originally but perhaps I was creating a different account time. I can still create an express account with a bank account, just can't add new ones after the fact..

Comment: yep, it works if you included https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create#create_account-external_account when creating the Account. But you can't create an external account separately for an Express account